# Java ускорить сумматор

Tags: java, оптимизация

Задача была считать число элементов массива и сам массив, а в ответ вывести сумму неодинаковых элементов. Однако столкнулся с проблемой нехватки времени. Как можно "ускорить" работы данного кода?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.*;

class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count;
        long X;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        count = in.nextInt();
        long[] Arr = new long[count];
        Arr[0] = in.nextInt();
        X = Arr[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < count; i++) {
            boolean sr = true;
            Arr[i] = in.nextInt();
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                    if (Arr[i] == Arr[j]) {
                        sr = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (sr == true)
                    X = X + Arr[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(X);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Если диапазон чисел не отрицательный и не больше 10^7, то можно использовать массив флагов, который показывает, какие элементы уже были.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count = in.nextInt();
    int MAX_ELEMENT = (int)10e7;
    boolean[] used = new boolean[MAX_ELEMENT + 1];
    long sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int x = in.nextInt();

        //если элемента x ещё не было
        if (!used[x]) {
            sum += x;
            used[x] = true; // помечаем, что x уже был
        }
    }

    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Иначе, используем множество (Set)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count = in.nextInt();

    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int x = in.nextInt();
        set.add(x);
    }

    long sum = 0;
    for (Integer x: set) {
        sum += x;
    }

    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Comment: Ещё есть [BitArray](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.bitarray?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: @Qwertiy, вы видимо имели ввиду: [BitSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html)? Дело в том, что из коробки в явке нет `BitArray` - есть только отдельная реализация и другие аналоги.

Comment: @And, тьфу, я язык попутал, но в джаве тоже есть что-нибудь. В крайнем случае BigInteger сойдёт.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно на большом количестве операций ввода данных (в данном случае, если речь идет о производительности этого алгоритма, то чисел достаточно много), то стоит использовать `BufferedReader`, а не `Scanner`. Далее, временная оценка представленного в вопросе алгоритма - `O(n^2)`, что будет очень долго работать на входном массиве из, скажем 10^5 чисел. Поэтому нужно оценку как-то уменьшить. Если нет информации о диапазоне чисел массива, то можно их сохранить в [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) (во множестве в Java могут храниться только различные объекты), скорость работы которого константна (для чисел уж точно):

> This class offers constant time performance for the basic operations (add, remove, contains and size), assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets.

Поэтому предложу следующее решение (в нем я считаю, что *ввод количества чисел происходит на первой строке, а на второй строке через пробел записан список чисел*):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    final int count = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

    final StringTokenizer numbers = new StringTokenizer(in.readLine(), " ");
    final Set<Long> distinctNumbers = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        distinctNumbers.add(Long.parseLong(numbers.nextToken()));
    }

    System.out.println(distinctNumbers.stream().mapToLong(Long::valueOf).sum());
}
```